# handling cpu intensive tasks : node vs php

Tags: php, node.js

i've been reading about nodejs lately , i came across lots of people talking against using nodejs in large apps with cpu intensive tasks because nodejs is single thread

so what makes multi thread languages like php more suitable for this kind of apps ? i mean if your task is using all of the server resources (cpu in this example) , is it going to matter if your programming language is single thread or using multiple threads for requests  ?  server is going to crash anyway ... i think !

here is some dummy code so i be able to post my question , pleas ignore this code :

```
get_next_node($node_1, $node_2){

    $dist = select distance from distances_table where node_2 = $node_2 and node_1 = $node_1

    $candidates_ar = select node_1 from distances_table where node_2 = $node_2 and distance < $dist

    $distances_ar = select distance from distances_table where node_1 = $node_1 and node_2 in ($candidates_ar) // e.g. $distances_ar[12] contains distance between node 12 and $node_1

    $min = 1000;
    foreach ($candidates_ar as $value){
        if ($distances_ar[$value] < $min){
            $min = $distances_ar[$value]
            $next_node = $value
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: PHP has multiple threading models; it depends on the server setup.

Comment: @MartinZeitler i know but you only have 1 cpu , so either single thread using all of it or multiple threads ... whats the difference  ? your app is going to crash anyway

Comment: A single script will use one thread by default; unless scheduling several with [`pthreads`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pthreads.php). If the CPU only has one physical thread, this most likely will be time-sliced (without the least performance gain). However, one web-server could still dispatch work to other servers; eg. by API interaction. On certain cloud hostings, once may also have "workers", which enable one to completely offload background work.

Comment: ... and that I only would have one CPU is definitely not the case.

Comment: 1 CPU can have anywhere from 1 to 128 cores .  Each thread can load down at most one physical core, less than that with hyperthreading.  So single thread vs. multiple threads can make a huge difference in performace.  Consider a 1 GHz CPU with 4 cores.  1 thread = 1 GHz of work, 4 threads = up to 4 GHz of work (though work rarely scales perfectly).  Also, MY app won't crash, it's too well written ;)

Comment: thanx guys i got it